# Split() with Filldown in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this query:

```
SELECT Query,QueryTargetingStatus,   SPLIT(Query," ") as SingleWords 
FROM `AdwordsDataSomething.SEARCH_QUERY_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` 
WHERE CampaignName LIKE '%en-us_atv_sch_brn_%' and QueryTargetingStatus = 'None'
ORDER BY Clicks DESC
```

How do I "fill down" the first and the second column?

Imagine I have 2000 query results like this...

Thx for any tips!
DZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to join with the elements of the array coming out of the `SPLIT`. You can use something like this:

```
SELECT Query,QueryTargetingStatus, SingleWords 
FROM `AdwordsDataAvast.SEARCH_QUERY_PERFORMANCE_REPORT`,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(Query," ")) AS SingleWords
WHERE CampaignName LIKE '%en-us_atv_sch_brn_%' and QueryTargetingStatus = 'None'
ORDER BY Clicks DESC
```